# myBatis xml mapper filer in use with Java interface - dynamic SQL query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc, mybatis, xmlmapper

I have problem. I didnt create MyBatis config. I heard it may work without it. I have Java interface called for example: `InterfaceDAO.java` and myBatis mapper `InterfaceDAO.xml`

InterfaceDAO.java :

```
@Mapper
public interface InterfaceDAO extends ApiConsumerDAO, ServiceDAO {

@Select("SELECT * FROM interface WHERE id = #{interfaceId}")
@Results({
        @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
        @Result(property = "date", column = "date"),
        @Result(property = "apiConsumer", column = "api_consumer", one = @One(select = "getApiConsumer")),
        @Result(property = "service", column = "service", one = @One(select = "getService")),
        @Result(property = "counterStatus", column = "counter_status"),
        @Result(property = "ratingProcessId", column = "rating_process_id"),
        @Result(property = "value", column = "value"),
        @Result(property = "createdDate", column = "created_date"),
        @Result(property = "modifiedDate", column = "modified_date")
})
InterfaceObject getInterfaceDAO(@Param("interfaceId") Integer interfaceId);


List<InterfaceObject > getInterfaceDAOList(@Param("apiConsumerIdsList") List<Integer> apiConsumerIdsList,
                                       @Param("serviceIdsList") List<Integer> serviceIdsList,
                                       @Param("dateFrom") Date dateFrom,
                                       @Param("dateTo") Date dateTo,
                                       @Param("status") InterfaceDAO.Status status);
}
```

InterfaceDAO.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="pl.net.manager.dao.InterfaceDAO">
    <select id="getInterfaceDAOList" parameterType="map" resultType="List">
        SELECT * FROM interface WHERE
        <if test="apiConsumerIdsList != null">
            #{apiConsumerIdsList} IS NULL OR api_consumer IN (#{apiConsumerIdsList,jdbcType=ARRAY})
        </if>
        <if test="serviceIdsList != null">
            #{serviceIdsList} IS NULL OR service IN (#{serviceIdsList,jdbcType=ARRAY})
        </if>
        <if test="status != null">
            #{status} IS NULL OR status IN (#{status,jdbcType=ARRAY})
        </if>
        <if test="dateFrom != null">
            #{dateFrom} IS NULL OR date &gt;= #{dateFrom,jdbcType=DATE}
        </if>
        <if test="dateTo != null">
            #{dateTo} IS NULL OR date &lt;= (#{dateTo,jdbcType=DATE})
        </if>
    </select>
</mapper>
```

And so the first method example called: getInterfaceDAO is working propely. But The second called: getInterfaceDAOList is more complicated and didnt work the same way the first one. That is why I want this particular method to use the xml mapper to gain data I want. The income arguments can be null or there can be several values in list.

Have you met with such a problem, and do you knows some best ways to solve this? This is my first contact with this.

I am using MyBatis and Postgres DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you can remove `#{apiConsumerIdsList} IS NULL` and similar occurances because you already checking for `!= null` in your `if` condition and that should suffice.

Secondly, for the `IN` clause you would have to use the `foreach` construct as shown below:

```
<foreach item="item" index="index" collection="apiConsumerIdsList" 
    open="(" separator="," close=")">
  #{item}
</foreach>
```

The above is applicable to all the `IN` clauses.

And the expression `#{dateFrom,jdbcType=DATE}` can simply be written as `#{dateFrom:DATE}`

Then coming to the `WHERE` clause, if multiple of the `if` conditions satisfy, then your `WHERE` clause will break because of the absence of `AND`, for that you can use `<where>` tag something like

```
<where>
    <if test="apiConsumerIdsList != null">
    api_consumer IN <foreach item="item" collection="apiConsumerIdsList" 
            open="(" separator="," close=")">
          #{item}
        </foreach>
    </if>
    <if test="serviceIdsList != null">
        AND service IN <foreach item="item" collection="serviceIdsList" 
                open="(" separator="," close=")">
              #{item}
            </foreach>(#{serviceIdsList,jdbcType=ARRAY})
    </if>
    <if test="status != null">
        AND status IN <foreach item="item" collection="status" 
                open="(" separator="," close=")">
              #{item}
            </foreach>
    </if>
    <if test="dateFrom != null">
        AND date &gt;= #{dateFrom:DATE}
    </if>
    <if test="dateTo != null">
        AND date &lt;= (#{dateTo:DATE})
    </if>
</where>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help. 

Unfortunately my main problem is to connect that interfaceDAO.java with those mapper. It is kinda like this doesnt see this mapper file and it doesnt want to use it, so I dont have a chance to test this solution

Comment: I should write item like this?
<if test="serviceIdsList != null">
        AND service IN <foreach DB_OBJECT ="JAVA_OBJECT" collection="serviceIdsList" 
                open="(" separator="," close=")">
              #{item}
            </foreach>(#{serviceIdsList,jdbcType=ARRAY})
    </if>

Comment: I meant DB_OBJECT, JAVA_OBJECT

Comment: Oh in that case just remove the `parameterType="map"` in the Mapper XML. It should be able to resolve the params based on the `@Param` annotation